# Rabbitmq max message per second

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

How to can config rabbitmq queue for consume 20 messages per second? if i have multiple queues,is it possible to do that for each queue?
such as:

**q1-> 20 message per second**

**q2-> 15 message per second**

Comment: What are you trying to do? Generally speaking g, you want consumers to handle messages as quickly as possible, so on the face of it, this would seem to be a somewhat quirky thing to want to do.

Answer (score 1):

When using message-driven consumers, you would have to do the throttling in the listener itself - add `Thread.sleep()` - or add an advice to the listener container's advice chain to separate the logic from your business code.

Generally, when wanting to control the rate of consumption, it might be easier to use a `RabbitTemplate.receive()` operation (or `RabbitTempalte.execute()` with `channel.basicGet()` if you want to defer the acknowledgment until the message is processed).

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` is likely not granular enough even for the relatively rough precision specified here, especially if the application is multi-threaded. You'd need to have some sort of spin-lock to guarantee precision, but even then, I wonder if this isn't an XY  problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure queue in RabbitMQ to serve a limited amount of messages per second, you must do it programmatically.

A ugly technique is to use a single listener for that queue (that consumes a message at a time), and add a `Thread.sleep(100L)` at the beginning of that method for 10 msg/s or a `Thread.sleep(66L)` for 15msg/s (more generally, wait for `1000/nMesgPerSecond`). This guarantees more-or-less a lower bound on time spent by that method.